# Python firebase admin sdk - Realtime update listener

Tags: python, django, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Do you have any plan to add realtime update listener in python firebase admin sdk? I have django api service. I want to change my current authentication and authorization system to firebase authentication. Realtime data update listener is not available for python. So I have to call firebase server  every time to authorize my user. It will make my api slower. What to do now for django in this situation?

[image]

Comment: Give information about how you create firebase user and tell us how you plan to integrate with Django user.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more? in each request `GET/POST` you send the provider token and you read firebase auth server to see if someone is authorised?